# McNemar test with multiple scores for the same subject

Tags: mcnemar-test

I am having a statistical issue:

- subjects receive a test with machine A and machine B.
- 3 experts classify whether the results of machine A and machine B are acceptable (1) or not (0).

From my understanding, the data are repeated measurements (as each subject gets tested by both machine A and B), so I should use McNemar test.
However, McNemar test only applies to 2x2 matrices as far as I know.

So how do I handle this:

- I cluster the opinions of all 3 experts and create a 2x2 table (ICC between their measurements is >0.80, so you could argue their agreement is strong enough to do that) (data_all below).

OR

- I create 3 separate 2x2 McNemar tables (one for each expert) (data_1, data_2, data_3).

Example code:

```
data_all <- matrix(c(100, 21, 100, 10), ncol=2, byrow=T)
mcnemar.test(data_all)

data_1 <- matrix(c(33, 7, 34, 3), ncol=2, byrow=T)
mcnemar.test(data_1)

data_2 <- matrix(c(33, 7, 33, 4), ncol=2, byrow=T)
mcnemar.test(data_2)

data_3 <- matrix(c(34, 7, 33, 3), ncol=2, byrow=T)
mcnemar.test(data_3)
```

I am sorry if this question seems very basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Cochran's *Q* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_Q_test). Just as the one way [repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design#Repeated_measures_ANOVA) generalizes the [paired *t* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_difference_test) to two or more measurements in the same individual (or more than two individuals matched per block), Cochran's *Q* test generalizes [McNemars' test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) to two or more measurements in the same individual (or more than two individuals matched per block). Applying Cochran's *Q* test to a 2x2 design gives identical results to McNemar's test, and one may use either McNemar's test, or all the 2x2 Cochran's *Q* tests for *post hoc* pairwise comparisons following a Cochran's *Q* omnibus test for more than 2 groups.

Cochran's *Q* is implemented in software in:

- within [R](https://r-project.org) in the [**RVAideMemoire**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RVAideMemoire/index.html) package as the as the **`cochran.qtest`** function,
- within [SAS](https://sas.com) in [**proc FREQ**](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/procstat_freq_sect034.htm),
- within SPSS in [**tests of *k* related samples**](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-cochran-q-test/), and
- within [Stata](http://stata.com/) as the [**cochranq**](http://alexisdinno.com/Software/index.shtml#cochranq) package (within Stata type **`net describe cochranq, from(http://alexisdinno.com/stata)`**). This package implements effect size measures by Berry, et al, and by Serlin, et al.

**References**
Berry, K. J., Johnston, J. E., and Paul W. Mielke, J. (2007). [An alternative measure of effect size for Cochran’s $Q$ test for related proportions](http://pms.sagepub.com/content/104/3_suppl/1236.full.pdf). *Perceptual and Motor Skills*, 104:1236–1242.

Cochran, W. G. (1950). [The comparison of percentages](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2332378). *Biometrika*, 37(3/4):256–266.

Serlin, R. C., Carr, J., and Marascuillo, L. A. (2007). [A measure of association for selected nonparametric procedures](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/bul/92/3/786/). *Psychological Bulletin*, 92:786–790.

Comment: As a note for R, the Cochran Q test can also be conducted with the *coin* package, using `symmetry_test(Response ~ Condition | Subject, data = Data, teststat = "quad")`.